# How to ignore some files in release with GIT

Tags: git, composer-php, nette

I develop a core for our Nette web projects. The core is injected as a library. Although I want to be able to test and try the functionalities of the core project without injecting it. So I had to add files needed to start the core project separately. This is really helpful while trying out new features, but I do not want to include these files in a release (but still be able to share on git, so colleagues can try it, too).

Are there any good practices how to deal with this situation?

I only found two options:

1. Do not commit these files into Git repository and share the files with colleagues through other repository - but here comes the compatibility problems.
2. Commit these files to Git and have a separate branch for release in which these files are deleted.

Comment: What's wrong with your branch solution? It looks good and easy to manage to me.

Comment: Sub-Modules? See this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: To be honest I have a terrible experience with sub-modules. [Why your company shouldn't use git submodules](https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules) may be worth a read.

Comment: I have the same experience as @kabanus. Submodules aren't the best solution (http://slopjong.de/2013/06/04/git-why-submodules-are-evil/)

Answer (score 13):

You may use [`export-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#git-archive-export-ignore) feature for this. Add this to your `.gitattributes` file:

```
/path/to/file/or/directory export-ignore
```

> **export-ignore**
>
> Files and directories with the attribute `export-ignore` won’t be added to archive files. See [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for details.